# Remember to call close() on all Realm instances but everything should be closed

Tags: android, realm

im having a workflow inside my app where the user can save something and after that a dialog appears with the hint to login. Inside my Android monitor the following Warning shows up: "Remember to call close() on all Realm instances. Realm /data/data/files/default.realm is being finalized without being closed, this can lead to running out of native memory."

Ive read the documentation (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) where the advice is to use "try-with-resources" (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances).
So every Realm Transaction is inside

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
// No need to close the Realm instance manually
}
```

and inside this block im using

```
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    // do Something
                }
            });
```

So in conclusion:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    // do Something
                }
            });
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this Warning shows up? Ive even tried to add a finally block where i close the Realm instance manually. But this does not avoid the warning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well are there any other cases where you use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`, primarily for example something like `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(...`?

Comment: Yes we do. We have some Repositories e.g. that we use: where we use something like this

`return Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Class.class).findAll();`

but when i use the try block there the app crashes with "This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.". Maybe we should call there realm.close() inside the finally block? To prevent the automatic close before everything is done?

Comment: Instead of having all your methods in the repository opening the instance you should open one Realm instance in the constructor and then close it again when the Repository is no longer used.

Comment: You should either create a repository instance per Realm and provide Realm as constructor parameter, OR (which is what I did) provide Realm as method parameter. Btw yes, those calls are the leaking Realm instances.

Comment: Thanks. I will try those solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive ended with the following solution. Inside my regular classes i've used the try catch block like this:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
   Repository.doSomething(realm);
} catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So im using the realm instances in my repository classes and they get closed after they returned the data inside the try catch block.

Thanks for your help!